# Loading external content (API) and prevent Layout-shifting (dynamically?)

Tags: javascript, css, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

[UPDATE]

I found 2 acceptable workarounds (with help from contributors):

- **Using a skeleton which contains a duplicate of the CSS / layout from
  the external source without content, but with transparent image
  placeholders.**
- **Lazyload external content where possible (at least below the fold)**

[/UPDATE]

I was wondering if one of you guys / gals maybe ran into the same trouble as me and found a working solution. Here's a screenshot of my website to give it a more clear view on the situation:

[image: Content loaded from 3rd party]

I understand that IF there's no height specified locally for that elements'location, the page starts 'shifting'. This would make it very hard to make everything looks perfect on every device (responsive) and when something changes, let's say the height changes of a sub-element, I manually need to recalculate the overall height (container) at every location / media-query.

I tried to load the external data as soon as possible, but even that get's noticed as CLS.
I'm very limited in configuration server-side, and even the configuration itself. The platform used is Lightspeed HQ, which makes use of twig-based templating without lot of tropical possibilities.

Thank you very much in advance for thinking with me!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to specify min height for those elements and show  [skeleton preloader](https://css-tricks.com/building-skeleton-screens-css-custom-properties/) during content loading

Comment: That's the way we always / do did this, but that's the whole reason for my post. In that case I need to specify a lot of (min-)heights for several resolutions, which need to be changed when there's something changed in the design

Comment: You can try to load products when they become visible in viewport, or just delay their loading to avoid coming to the lighthouse(but those are looks like a bit hacky)